# What's wrong with my looping argument?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Let us say $f(x)$ be a real valued function whose first derivative is known to exist and is equal to $g(f(x))$, where $g(x)$ is another real-valued function whose ($g(x)$'s ) derivative is not confirmed to exist.

If $f'(x)=0$ at $x=x_0$, will it imply that $f(x)$ is constant from $x=x_0$ to infinity ?

My looping approach:
(In all the below, $h\rightarrow0$)

Given : $f'(x_0)=g(f(x_0))=0$

$f'(x_0)=0$ , so $f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)/h=0$
so, $f(x_0+h)=f(x_0)$
so, $f'(x_0+h)=g(f(x_0+h))=g(f(x_0))=0$
so, $f'(x_0+h)=f(x_0+h+h)-f(x_0+h)/h=0$
so, $f(x_0+h+h)=f(x_0+h)$
so, $f'(x_0+h+h)=g(f(x_0+h+h))=g(f(x_0+h))=g(f(x_0))=0$

Now the same thing loops again and again , thus $f'(x)=0$ when $x$ belongs to $[x_0 , \infty]$

So $f(x)$ must be constant from $x=x_0$ to infinity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several key steps in your looping argument seem to be incorrect, especially the first one, in which you write $$\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}=0.$$ This is not correct, what is correct is that  $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}=0.$$ This is an important difference, and as far as I can see it invalidates the entire argument.

Comment: Can you please explain why? Is it because lim h->0 f(x_0+h)=f(x_0) ? That is , as h tends to 0, the limiting value of f(x) will be equal to f(x_0) and not the exact value? That is , f(x_0+h) not equal to f(x_0) but lim h->0 f(x_0+h)=f(x_0) ?

Comment: The equality is not true. There might not be any $h>0$ such that $f(x_0+h)=f(x_0)$. For a concrete example take $f(x)=x$...

Comment: I have updated my comment. Is it correct?

Comment: No, it is not correct, and what you are trying to prove is not correct. A counterexample is $f(x)=x^2$ at $x_0=0$. The derivative is zero at that point but it is not constant from then on. I suggest you review the concept of  a limit. Further modifications should go into a separate question.

Comment: (I mean please check my first comment. Is it correct? Not the question)

Comment: Your first comment in this thread seems fine...

Comment: Thank you very much!!! You made my Day!!! Thanks once again.